# Solving an inequality wirh Erfc

Tags: inequality, monotone-functions, error-function

I am trying to prove the following statement.

$$ 2\sqrt{2}\sigma - k \exp{\frac{k^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sqrt{\pi} \textit{Erfc}\Big[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \Big] >0 $$

My approach is as follows:

It is evidet Using L'Hôpital's rule yields:

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} k \exp{\frac{k^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sqrt{\pi} \textit{Erfc}\Big[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \Big]= \sqrt{2}\sigma. $$

or, alternatively,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} 2\sqrt{2}\sigma - k\exp{\frac{k^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sqrt{\pi} \textit{Erfc}\Big[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \Big] = \sqrt{2}\sigma >0.$$

As far as I concerned, it is now necessary to prove that $ k \exp{\frac{k^2}{2\sigma^2}}\sqrt{\pi} \textit{Erfc}\Big[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \Big]$ is a monotonically non-decreasing function. However, I am fail to do it so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  $\sigma >0$, let $k=\sqrt{2} \sigma  t$ and you need to prove that
$$2 >\sqrt{2 \pi }\, t\,  e^{t^2}\,\text{erfc}(t)$$ Using the expansion for large values of $t$, we have 
$$t  e^{t^2}\text{erfc}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi } t^2}+\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{\pi }
   t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)$$ Making the rhs to be
$$\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} t^2}+\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}
   t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)$$ Then ... ?